# Vim autocmd - Run command on WinEnter for every buffer name EXCEPT {name}

Tags: vim

I have an autocmd which runs every time I exit and enter a window.  It turns off the `number` for every window except the current one.

```
au WinEnter * setlocal number
au WinLeave * setlocal nonumber
```

However, I do not want line numbers in a NERDTree window.  Setting `g:NERDTreeShowLineNumbers` to `0` doesn't help either.  Is there any way of having the autocommand run on `WinEnter` only when the window is *not* a NERDTree window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess:

```
au WinEnter * if !exists("b:NERDTreeType") | setlocal number | endif
au WinLeave * if !exists("b:NERDTreeType") | setlocal nonumber | endif
```

Note: I do not use NerdTree so I have not tested any of this.

Comment: I should have thought of using an if statement.  Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

The following works when `vim` is opened with a file, as well as when you switch in and out of NERDTree windows:

```
au FileType * if !(&ft ==? "nerdtree") | setlocal number | endif
au WinEnter * if !(&ft ==? "nerdtree") | setlocal number | endif
au WinLeave * if !(&ft ==? "nerdtree") | setlocal nonumber | endif
```

Tested on CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 with

- `vim` 7.4
- NERDTree 5.0.0